# Lua pathfinding code needs optimization

Tags: performance, optimization, lua, path-finding, roblox

After working on my code for a while, optimizing the most obvious things, I've resulted in this:

```
function FindPath(start, finish, path)
    --Define a table to hold the paths
    local paths = {}
    --Make a default argument
    path = path or {start}
    --Loop through connected nodes
    for i,v in ipairs(start:GetConnectedParts()) do
        --Determine if backtracking
        local loop = false
        for i,vv in ipairs(path) do
            if v == vv then
                loop = true
            end
        end
        if not loop then
            --Make a path clone
            local npath = {unpack(path)}
            npath[#npath+1] = v
            if v == finish then
                --If we reach the end add the path
                return npath
            else
                --Otherwise add the shortest part extending from this node
                paths[#paths+1] = FindPath(v, finish, npath) --NOTED HERE
            end
        end
    end
    --Find and return the shortest path
    if #paths > 0 then
        local lengths = {}
        for i,v in ipairs(paths) do
            lengths[#lengths+1] = #v
        end
        local least = math.min(unpack(lengths))
        for i,v in ipairs(paths) do
            if #v == least then
                return v
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The problem being, the line noted gets some sort of game script timeout error (which I believe is a because of mass recursion with no yielding). I also feel like once that problem is fixed, it'll probably be rather slow even on the scale of a pacman board. Is there a way I can further optimize it, or perhaps a better method I can look into similar to this?

**UPDATE**: I finally decided to trash my algorithm due to inefficiency, and implemented a Dijkstra algorithm for pathfinding. For anybody interested in the source code it can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Xivf9mwv

Answer (score 1):

You know that Roblox provides you with the PathfindingService? It uses C-side A* pathing to calculate quite quickly. I'd recommend using it

http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/PathfindingService

Comment: I am aware of this, and I use it often, but I'm working on code for a friend who needs AI to walk a side-walk system (PathfindingService would have them walking across roads)

Comment: Then can we have your FindPath code? I suspect that it may be that function causing the slowdown.

Comment: Oh it's recursive... In that case I expect that yes, the issue is a recursion limit expressed by ROBLOX. I advise creating your nodes in a new manner. Perhaps calculate the length of your sidewalks rather than the connecting parts. I'd create a grid of every 5 or so studs along such sidewalks that create the node path.

Comment: If I made the operation less expensive I might be able to get it to work.

Comment: I have a pacman board, full of nodes that are 4*0.1*4 in size. The board is 28 by 36 nodes, there's 360ish nodes that are walkable, the rest are walls. This is what I am using to test it.

Comment: Can you denote which nodes are walkable and which are not? Are they named accordingly?

Comment: Only the walkables ones are connected, so the function has no trouble differing between them.

Comment: I set it up to wait() every so many iterations. If I make it too high it doesn't work, but too low and it takes too long. I really think I need to lesson how expensive it is.

Comment: Give me awhile. I'll see if I can create something. It's been awhile since I did roblox lua however.

Comment: When I said 28 by 36 I meant 28 by 31, it's too late to edit it

Comment: Okay that'd be great, thanks. I'll get back to you later/tomorrow.

Comment: Try using this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

It's super efficient and I think it'll work better for what you're doing. I'll try to make something in Rbx lua if I have time

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if A* is the way to go. Each node is the same distance/cost as any other, so why take it into account?

Comment: Try dijkstra's maybe then, it's a simplified A* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Because you're not keeping a list of traveled nodes. Like part a travels to part b, and part b travels back to a, ad infinitum.

Comment: I recommend an a* variant because it does a good job at keeping track of traveled nodes.

Comment: I am though. You'll notice I loop over the current path to insure I'm not backtracking.

Comment: It loops through the path but doesn't check the previous nodes in the path.

Comment: After quite a bit of work trying to make Dijkstra's algorithm in Lua code, I finally managed this: pastebin.com/KawUKbu8But it still seems to be working too hard. Did I do the algorithm properly?

Comment: Wait nevermind. I just need to fix the order of the path it returns it now, but it seems to be working (it doesn't timeout).. Thanks, suggest Dijkstra in your answer so I can accept

Comment: My gosh I hate flooding the comments (and probably your notifications) but I found the problem, I was using #Q when I implemented it as a dictionary, in case you're interested in the final product: http://pastebin.com/Xivf9mwv

Comment: Works? Quickly too, I hope?

Comment: suggest Dijkstra in your answer so I can accept – warspyking Jan 23 at 3:21

Answer (score 0):

Try to remodel your algorithm to make use of tail calls. This is a great mechanism available in Lua.

A tail call is a type of recursion where your function returns a function call as the last thing it does. Lua has proper tail calls implementation and it will dress this recursion as a 'goto' under the scenes, so your stack will never blow.

Passing 'paths' as one of the arguments of FindPath might help with that.

Comment: This would be nice if roblox used Lua 5.2, but alas, it used Lua 5.1

Comment: This code is meant for ROBLOX, where tailcalls are actually disabled.

Comment: @EinsteinK They're not *disabled*, rather **unimplemented**. ROBLOX uses a modified version of Lua 5.1, but Lua only introduced tailcalls in 5.2.

Comment: @warspyking Lua 5.1 does have tail calls: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html as  seen under _2.5.8 - Function Calls_. ROBLOX did have tail calls, but removed them less than 3y ago. Here's an almost ancient forum post by Stravant about it: http://forum.roblox.com/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=132422268. Also, where did you get the idea that tail calls only got added in 5.2?

Comment: @Einstein I cannot find where I found it... It was on an official Lua source, but I guess it was fixed.

Comment: @EtieneDalcol Apparently to make debugging easier, as a tailcall reuses the callstack, which would make it lose some information. That's the main reason they told us.

Answer (score -1):

I saw your edit about ditching the code, but just to help others stumbling on this question:

- ipairs is slower than pairs, which is slower than a *numeric for*-loop.
  If performance matters, never use ipairs, but use a *for i=1,#tab* loop
- If you want to clone a table, use a for-loop. Sometimes, you **have** to use unpack *(returning dynamic amount of trailing nils)*, but this is **not** such a case. Unpack is also a slow function.

Replacing *ipairs* with *pairs* or numeric for-loops and using loops instead of *unpack* will increase the performance **a lot**.

If you want to get the lowest value in a table, use this code snippet:

```
local lowestValue = values[1]
for k,v in pairs(values) do
    if v < lowestValue then
        lowestValue = k,v
    end
end
```

This could be rewritten for your path example as so:

```
local least = #path[1]
for k,v in pairs(path) do
    if #v < least then
        least = v
    end
end
```

I have to admit, you're very inventive. Not a lot of people would use math.min(unpack(tab)) *(not counting the fact it's bad)*

Comment: ipairs is FASTER than pairs because it only iterates over the ARRAY part, rather than the hash. Not sure where you got the idea pairs was faster.

Comment: And why is unpacking a table to be used for math.min **bad** unpack is for unpacking a table. Using it for unpacking it as args for math.min seems fairly logical to me.

Comment: And I tested your for loop VS unpack argument. I cloned an array with 7999 items, 1000 times and output red how long they took. The for loop took 9 seconds, whereas the unpack took 2. (Granted my test was in Lua 5.2, but surely the test would give about the same results on roblox)

Comment: I just tested pairs VS ipairs using an array of 10k and 5M entries. Only in the case of the 10k was ipairs **sometimes** slightly faster than pairs. Most of the time, pairs was still faster, although the difference is almost not worth mentioning.

Comment: Using unpack isn't that bad, as it's actually faster than cloning a table using a forloop. Unpack can only unpack 7999 elements though. Doing unpack(tab) when _tab_ contains 8k elements will lead to the error **too many results to unpack**. Getting the smallest value in a table is indeed faster than a for-loop _(about 10 times)_, but your code also uses a loop to get the actual path from the minimum value. Just comparing "v == least" would already make your code slower in at least 50% of the cases. Combined with #v it's certain that using the unpack approach would be slower most of the time.

Comment: Strange ipairs always turns up faster for me.

Comment: I would never of had 8K elements though. And you said unpack was slow in your answer, which it is not

Comment: I've tested it with 50 elements now. In that case, _unpack_ is only then _(half of the time)_ faster than a for-loop. _(again assuming you need to get the path from the lowest pathlength). Also, I said the code would be slower using _v == least_ compared to _#v == least_. Apparently the length version is faster, probably because of a simple number comparison. _(This is why most people, including me, prefer already created pathfinding code)_

Comment: I think you need to revise/delete this answer.